# Foreach em Post PHP retorno

Tags: php

Tenho um form em que envio via post os dados do formulário e capturo por um `foreach`.

No `form` tenho um botão em que crio novos `input` pelo `append` jQuery, `input` com mesmo `name`.

O problema que tenho é que ao cadastrar apenas um item, o `insert` é realizado normalmente, mas, ao informar mais itens, é inserido apenas o primeiro conjunto de dados, é o segundo retorna com valores 0.

O código para recuperar os valores são:

```
foreach( $_POST['numero'] as $key => $n ) {


    $data_cadastro = explode('/', $_POST['dt_cadastro'][$key]);
    $data_cadastro = $data_cadastro[2].'-'.$data_cadastro[1].'-'.$data_cadastro[0];
    
    
    $telefone_numero = str_replace("(", "", $_POST['numero'][$key]);
    $telefone_numero = str_replace(")", "", $telefone_numero);
    $telefone_numero = str_replace("-", "", $telefone_numero);
    $telefone_numero = str_replace(" ", "", $telefone_numero);

    
    $_POST['id_usuario']         = $_POST['id_usuario'][$key];
    $_POST['numero']             = $telefone_numero;
    $_POST['id_operadora']  = $_POST['id_operadora'][$key];
    $_POST['dt_cadastro']        = $data_cadastro;
    $_POST['status']             = $_POST['status'][$key];
    $_POST['id_numero']          = $_POST['id_numero'][$key];

    $result     = DBCreate($tbl, $_POST, TRUE, TRUE);

}
```

Ao dar um print no post, recebo isso:

```
Array
(
    [id_usuario] => 3
    [numero] => 82999999999
    [id_operadora] => 1
    [dt_cadastro] => 2016-04-14
    [status] => 1
    [id_numero] => 23232323
)



Array
(
    [id_usuario] => 
    [numero] => 2
    [id_operadora] => 
    [dt_cadastro] => --0
    [status] => 
    [id_numero] => 3
)
```

Existe algo errado com meu `foreach`?

Os campos de mesmo nome estão com mesmo `name`, seguindo um padrão: `name="id_numero[]"`

Verifique que ao dar um `print` no post antes do `foreach` recebo:

```
Array
(
    [id_usuario] => 31
    [numero] => Array
        (
            [0] => (82) 99999-9999
            [1] => (82) 8888-8888
        )

    [id_operadora] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
        )

    [dt_cadastro] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14/04/2016
            [1] => 14/04/2016
        )

    [status] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [id_numero] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23232323
            [1] => 9830048884
        )

)
```

Ou seja, os valores estão corretos antes do `foreach`

Comment: Eu não entendi porque vc está reescrevendo o $_POST, além disso, vc colocou um value, `$n`, já traria o valor.

Comment: Estou fazendo manutenção num sistema que não conheço, a função de insert no BD captura os posts do form, tive que reescreve-la para funcionar. Vlw

Comment: mas o ideal é vc passar um array novo, neste caso...

Comment: Apenas não substitui o POST como estava fazendo este código, inseri as colunas e os campos diretamente no campo DBCreate, e tudo passou a funcionar normalmente. Que pena que vou ter que editar o sistema inteiro, ô código mal projetado :(

Comment: Isso já percebi.

Comment: Conserta o título aí, Forech tá errado, é Foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os campos `numero`, `id_operadora`, `dt_cadastro`, `status` e `id_numero` são arrays com chaves numéricas crescentes, então você pode processá-las num `foreach` assim:

```
$key = 0;
while ( isset( $_POST['numero'][$key] ) )
{
    ...
    $key++;
}
```

Os demais acessos são do jeito que já está trabalhando, com `$_POST['numero'][$key]`.

Mas repare que `id_usuario` não é um array, e portanto que `$_POST['id_usuario'][$key]` parece estar errado.

---

Da segunda parte, perceba que você está apagando seus próprios dados. Por exemplo a linha:

```
$_POST['id_usuario'] = $_POST['id_usuario'][$key];
```

Transforma o `$_POST['id_usuario']` de um array para um valor único, por isso só funciona uma vez.

O que você tem de fazer aí é criar um **novo** array, apenas com os dados que `DbCreate` precisa, e deixar intocado o `$_POST`.

Comment: Opa, obrigado por responder André, inseri o while dentro do foreach, houve o mesmo, os demais campos vieram zerados. Corrigi o id_usuario, vlw mesmo.

Comment: Dei um echo no post após dentro do while, me retornou os mesmos dados do echo anterior. O que será que há de errado?

Comment: Solucionado, vlw André

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
O id_usuario é uma string. Pegue-o dessa forma direta:
*/
if (isset($_POST['id_usuario'])) {
    $data['usuario']['id'] = $_POST['id_usuario'];

    /*
    Presupõe-se que o array depende da existência do id do usuário, por isso colocamos aqui dentro da condicional do id_usuario
    */
    if (isset($_POST['numero'])) {

        /* 
        Aqui iteramos o array "numero", o qual possui índices iguais aos outros arrays. 
        Isso tem alto risco de falhas, por isso é recomendado criar condicionais mais consistentes.
        Exemplo abaixo:
        */
        foreach ($_POST['numero'] as $k => $v) {
            $data[$k]['id_operadora'] = (isset($_POST['id_operadora'][$k])? $_POST['id_operadora'][$k] : null);
            $data[$k]['dt_cadastro'] = (isset($_POST['dt_cadastro'][$k])? $_POST['dt_cadastro'][$k] : null);
            $data[$k]['status'] = (isset($_POST['status'][$k])? $_POST['status'][$k] : null);
            $data[$k]['id_numero'] = (isset($_POST['id_numero'][$k])? $_POST['id_numero'][$k] : null);
        }

    }

/*
    Teste. Imprime o que foi extraído do $_POST.
    Daqui para frente deve ainda fazer mais verificações, validar os dados, etc.
    */
    print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser feito com for

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['numero']);$i++) {
    $id_usuario    = $_POST['id_usuario'][$i];
    $numero        = $_POST['numero'][$i];
    $id_operadora  = $_POST['id_operadora'][$i];
    $dt_cadastro   = $_POST['dt_cadastro'][$i];
    $status        = $_POST['status'][$i];
    $id_numero     = $_POST['id_numero'][$i];
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).